# How make QListWidgetItem autosize to its content, and fit into its QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Here is an elastic layout of a single item i'm trying to design :

[image: my desired layout]

Please find below the code i'm using to display that custom QListWidgetItem in a QlistWidget.
But the layout does not look as expected :

- custom widget does not fit the width of the list, I don't want a horizontal scroll bar
- even with setWordWrap set to True, long description does not display the whole text and is cut in its height

The code :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(400, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

class customWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, name, date, desc, parent = None):
        super(customWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        
        # feed labels
        self.labelName = QLabel(name)
        self.labelName.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
        self.labelName.setStyleSheet('''font: bold;''')

        self.labelDate = QLabel(date)
        self.labelDate.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)

        self.labelDesc = QLabel(desc)
        self.labelDesc.setFrameShape(QFrame.Box)
        self.labelDesc.setWordWrap(True)

        # layout
        self.Hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hlayout.addWidget(self.labelName)
        self.Hlayout.addStretch()
        self.Hlayout.addWidget(self.labelDate)

        self.Vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vlayout.addLayout(self.Hlayout)
        self.Vlayout.addWidget(self.labelDesc)
        
        self.setLayout(self.Vlayout)

def feed_list():
    myArray = [
        ("paul meneck", "21/09/1969", "blond whith red hat"),
        ("boby la pointe", "16/08/1972", "brown shoes"),
        ("julius con-meraz de la fuego", "07/12/1980","this is a very long description"
            "with more and more bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
            "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
            "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla "
            "and finaly the END OF THAT LONG DESCRIPTION"),
        ("roberto umportes", "14/01/1957", "another description for that roberto")
    ]
    for var in myArray:
        item = QListWidgetItem()
        widget = customWidget(var[0], var[1], var[2])
        item.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())
        ui.listWidget.addItem(item)
        ui.listWidget.setItemWidget(item, widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    feed_list()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question by implying a (possible) solution, as it would make it confusing to other users, and linking to external sites in a question/answer body is discouraged, as those links might expire. I will update my answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the QListWidget is mandatory, then you have to provide only the hint for the required orientation.

The returned sizeHint of a widget is always a size that *recommended*, aka is the *optimal* size to ensure that all widget have the correct size to show their contents (which is usually bigger than the *minimum* size).

The sizeHint of an item view, instead, is the default size that the item will use, and since QListWidget has no horizontal header, there's no direct way to "stretch" the contents to a size smaller than the hint.

The solution is to invalidate the orientation of the size hint for which you're not interested, by setting its value to -1:

```
    widget = customWidget(var[0], var[1], var[2])
    hint = widget.sizeHint()
    hint.setWidth(-1)
    item.setSizeHint(hint)
```

Comment: no more luck with hint.setWidth(-1), even worse list is empty

Comment: I tried your code with the only change above (you have removed the other `item.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())`, right?) and it works, even with other styles. Are you correctly trying with the code you provided?

Comment: Yes, code provided, with your update (without my setSizeHint of course), and list stay empty. Running python 3.9.2 under w10pro. Result with my own code: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PznaZ3Nr6mrXgrIA8lR4yJarVBY2LSmD/view?usp=sharing)   The only enhancement i got is using hint.setWidth(1) (not minus 1): [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19vlC8YgfKIcZyQRpZylJoaKJMT4r70uL/view?usp=sharing)    But both results truncate the end of labels

Comment: Please be more precise from the beginning when saying that something "doesn't work", from your first comment it it seemed that anything has changed at all. The vertical truncation is a limitation that *has* to be expected when trying to do something like this, as QLabel are pretty complex objects (yes, they're not as simple as they look). Item views have limited control on widget set for indexes, as their priority is completely different. May I ask you why do you need to use a QListWidget?

Comment: I did not succeed displaying the initial layout i mentioned in the beginning, each time a label in truncated, or long description does not show entierly. Interesting answer, in fact i'm trying to use QListWidget because i wrongly though it would be easy to manipulate. What would you suggest instead of QListWidget ? Thanks for your help Musicamante

Comment: The main purpose of a QListWidget, as with its QListView base class and all QAbstractItemViews is to provide display and (possibly) manipulation of data. While they *can* be used for other purposes, those cases are very specific and the limitations of the view (which by default has a different scope) must be considered, as explained in the previous comment. If you don't need to display/manipulate data, QListWidget is probably not the correct solution. What are you trying to achieve that couldn't be done using a basic QScrollArea?

Comment: I just need an item to be selected (with multi selection). I don't know QScrollArea, i'll give it a try

Comment: Then I'd suggest you to add a "selected" variable to the custom widget and implement its paintEvent to show a background if the variable set. Here is a possible implementation (note that I revised your code for various reasons, see the comments): https://gist.github.com/MaurizioB/b16e1f7afe6608fb245d0e44f016aa3c

Comment: Wow ! I now have to understand all these nested QT widgets, but I must admit that it does exactly what I'm looking for. So a hudge THANK YOU for your precious help !!

Comment: @Rodolphe you're very welcome. I'll edit the answer to include the solution, even if it's slightly off-topic, so you could mark it as accepted if you want to.